# Ruby on Rails with sql server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

There is a chance I will have to make a project using RoR with a SQL Server 2008 r2 database. Is there any complication with using sql server as opposed to mysql when it comes to developing with RoR?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only difference between the mysql adapter and the SQLServer adapter is that the later depends on the freetds gem.  And when you first setup up your connection,  you may have to deal with some simple utilities that come with freetds to verify or debug the connection.  Once you are connecting,  there is no difference in the way you deal with the database,  no where in your RoR code is ANYTHING specific to SQLServer vs. mysql, it's all handled by the SQLServer adapter and freetds.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too much of an issue; see this [screencast on Rails 3, Ruby 1.9.2, Windows 2008, and SQL Server 2008](http://rhnh.net/2010/10/10/rails-3-ruby-1-9-2-windows-2008-and-sql-server-2008-tutorial) by Xavier Shay.

If you do run into issues while working on this project, StackOverflow is always there to rescue you ;-)